# Can SWF (not in an HTML page) load content from localhost?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've just created a flash video that loads content from a specific URL, in localhost.
Let's say that my url is `"http://localhost/mysite/index.php"`

Now, while debugging it into flash professional all works fine, but my problem is that I (if possible) want to use the published .swf file NOT inside an html page, but as-is.
This because I have to load it inside a specific software.

Obviously when I try to execute it, it cannot load my remote page, unless I reach it in the blowser.

Is there a solution?!
Thanks...

Update: these are my trusted locations
[image]

Comment: Is this file going to be released to the public, or is it something for your own personal use? If it's the latter, you may be able to do some fiddling with your "trusted location settings" in the Flash Player Settings.

Comment: It's absolutely for my personal use. I've already tried to fiddling with the Flash Player settings but it don't works...other ideas?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your trusted locations?

Comment: Updated. I've tried to add many rows...but any of those seems to work. I think it's impossible to let swf file communicate with remote domains, not inside an html page...

Comment: Try adding the local path of your file i.e. c:\projects\yourProject

Comment: Already done :) the first and the second lines are the local path where is the script that I wanna load. It's automatically overwritten as you can see...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42979/discussion-between-marcela-and-ilsavo)